# including wp-load.php outside of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress is currently installed in the root at creativiii.com . I want to load wp-load.php from the folder /random-games/login/index.php

I cannot find a way to get to wp-load.php if I'm outside of my root. I tried with creativiii.com/wp-load.php, I tried with /var/www/creativiii.com/wp-load.php, and it just refuses to connect to the file and keeps giving me a HTTP ERROR 500.

I know the script I have works from the root, the problem is definitely with wp-load. How do I get this to work?

Here's the current contents of my very simple script

```
<?php
require( 'creativiii.com/wp-load.php' );
get_header();

echo 'new content outside WordPress';

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php');
get_header();

echo 'new content outside WordPress';

get_footer();
?>
```